# Regex to match pattern of two digit number before a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a text as so:

`text = "There is 18 years of experience in marketing, with 5 years in sales."`

I want to create a regex rule that will extract `\d\d + "years"` so that it may extract any one and two digit number followed by the keyword 'years' or 'Years' or 'Yrs' from any corpus.

Expected output: ["18 year", "5 years"]

I tried

```
text = re.findall(r'\d\d +years', text)
```

which returned `None`

How to get this?

Comment: Any two-digit number? "5 years"?

Comment: One or two digits. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern: `\d{1,2} (?:yrs|years?)` with flag `IGNORECASE` in python.

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oHAnRH/2)

**Explanation**

- `\d{1,2}`: capture one or two-digit.
- `(?:`: is a non-captured group.
- `yrs|years`: this captures "yrs" or "years". (case-insensitive)
- `?`: this after "y" means "s" can be or not.